# Spanish Cadastre Owner

Tags: geospatial

I have done a few researches about the spanish cadastre. I found the incredible QGIS plug-in "Spanish Inspire Catastral Downloader" which allows to retrieve the parcels.

I am now asking if there is a dataset linking the parcels and the owners. As a comparaison, in France, a dataset of the parcels owned by a moral person -ie a company- is published.

Is there something like this in Spain ?